# Finding lowest value of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, min

I am making a game with obstacles currently and I want to find the object with the lowest X value.
Here is an example of an array.

```
var array = [{x:500, y:400}, {x:80, y:400}, {x:900, y:400}];
```

I want to be able to determine what is the lowest X in this group(*80*) and return it to me.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use a sort, and then pick the first/last depending on the order of your sort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: Check this out: `array.sort(({ x: x1 }, { x: x2 }) => x1 - x2)[0]` // {x: 80, y: 400}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to sort the array or use an external library. You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to find the object with minimum `x` in linear time:

```js
const array = [{x:500, y:400}, {x:80, y:400}, {x:900, y:400}];
const minX = array.reduce((acc, curr) => curr.x < acc.x ? curr : acc, array[0] || undefined);
console.log(minX)
```

Comment: I prefer this to sorting

Comment: Just beware of empty array, becouse of exeption:  'Reduce of empty array with no initial value'

Comment: @FFire Yes. Updated to not throw an error when empty array is used

Answer (score 0):

You can use lodash

```js
var array = [{
  x: 500,
  y: 400
}, {
  x: 80,
  y: 400
}, {
  x: 900,
  y: 400
}];
console.log(_.minBy(array, 'x'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: May you also suggest non-library solution? Since lodash has not been used nor asked for?

Answer (score -1):

```js
let min = Infinity
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if (array[i].x<min) min = array[i].x
}
```

Here min is your answer. There might be easier way to do this, but his gets the job done.

Comment: OP wants the object with the lowest `x`, not just the lowest value `x`.

Answer (score -1):

sort and get the first

```js
var arr = [{
  x: 500,
  y: 400
}, {
  x: 80,
  y: 400
}, {
  x: 900,
  y: 400
}];
arr.sort((a, b) => a.x < b.x ? -1 : (a.x > b.x ? 1 : 0));
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Actually you don't need ternary operators, just subtraction

Comment: This is inefficient. It's `O(n log(n))` instead of `O(n)`.